# Trying to read a byte (Word8) by offset in Haskell and getting various error

Tags: haskell, byte

I have a file called test2.hs below where I'm trying to read a byte (Word8) by offset in a binary file and use it as Int. Below example is trying to read the 2nd byte in the binary file.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.Binary.Get

getuint8 = do
    uint8 <- getWord8
    return uint8

readuint8 :: BS.ByteString -> Int -> Int
readuint8 contents startpos = do
    return $ runGet getuint8 (drop startpos contents)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let myfile = "DATA.BIN"
    contents <- BS.readFile myfile
    let stuff = readuint8 contents 1
    print stuff
```

Not too sure why I'm getting the below errors:

```
test2.hs:12:9: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘m0 Word8’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        return $ runGet getuint8 (drop startpos contents)
      In the expression:
        do { return $ runGet getuint8 (drop startpos contents) }
      In an equation for ‘readuint8’:
          readuint8 contents startpos
            = do { return $ runGet getuint8 (drop startpos contents) }

test2.hs:12:35: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘BS.ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘[a0]’
    • In the second argument of ‘runGet’, namely
        ‘(drop startpos contents)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘runGet getuint8 (drop startpos contents)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        return $ runGet getuint8 (drop startpos contents)

test2.hs:12:49: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a0]’
                  with actual type ‘BS.ByteString’
    • In the second argument of ‘drop’, namely ‘contents’
      In the second argument of ‘runGet’, namely
        ‘(drop startpos contents)’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘runGet getuint8 (drop startpos contents)’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Type Errors

Most of your issues are type errors.  These are the most common type of compiler error message when writing a Haskell program.  Let's look at an example function:

```
readuint8 :: BS.ByteString -> Int -> Int
```

This function will accept a `ByteString` and `Int` then return an `Int`.

```
readuint8 contents startpos
```

So contents is the `ByteString` and `startpos` is the `Int`.

```
       = do
    return $
```

For some reason you are using do notation, but the type (`Int`) is not a monad (which would appear as something like `IO Int`, `[Int]` or more generally `m Int`).  **Issue 1** You should not be using either `do` or `return` here and instead just use the expression, for which you have:

```
runGet getuint8 (drop startpos contents)
```

The `drop` function defined in the prelude operates over lists, not ByteStrings.  **Issue 2** You probably want `BS.drop`.  Since bytestring drop requires an `Int64` parameter, which is distinct from an `Int`, you should convert via `fromIntegral`.  Note that dropping bytes implies `startpos` is zero indexed.

Now the type is... whatever `getuint8`'s type is.  Notice this function definition is superfluous - it is equal to `getuint8 = getWord8`.  You didn't explicitly type `getuint8`, but the type is inferred to be a `Get Word8`.  **Issue 3** The mixing of `Word8` and `Int` types is a problem - `readuint8` expects an `Int` and that is different than `Word8`.  You can convert between integral types using `fromIntegral` so consider:

```
fromIntegral (runGet getuint8 (BS.drop (fromIntegral startpos) contents))
```

### Alternative

Consider just unpacking the bytestring and indexing into that:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let myfile = "DATA.BIN"
    contents <- BS.readFile myfile
    let stuff = drop 1 (BS.unpack contents)
    case stuff of
        (firstByte:restOfTheBytes)    -> print firstByte
         [] {- empty list of bytes -} -> putStrLn "The file was not that long."
```

Consider some slight compaction of your original construction:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print . runGet getWord8 . BS.drop 1 =<< BS.readFile "DATA.BIN"
```

Which reads from right to left as read the file, drop a byte, get the first Word8 value, print the value.